# Why don't simultaneous updates to the same record in sqlalchemy fail?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, transactions, sqlalchemy

(Sorry in advance for the long question. I tried to break it up into sections to make it clearer what I'm asking. Please let me know if I should add anything else or reorganize it at all.)

**Background:**

I'm writing a web crawler that uses a producer/consumer model with jobs (pages to crawl or re-crawl) stored in a postgresql database table called crawler_table. I'm using SQLAlchemy to access and make changes to the database table. The exact schema is not important for this question. The important thing is that I (will) have multiple consumers, each of which repeatedly selects a record from the table, loads the page with phantomjs, and then writes information about the page back to the record.

It can happen on occasion that two consumers select the same job. This is not itself a problem; however, it is important that if they update the record with their results simultaneously, that they make consistent changes. It's good enough for me to just find out if an update would cause the record to become inconsistent. If so, I can deal with it.

**Investigation:**

I initially assumed that if two transactions in separate sessions read then updated the same record simultaneously, the second one to commit would fail. To test that assumption, I ran the following code (simplified slightly):

```
SQLAlchemySession = sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(my_postgresql_uri))

class Session (object):
    # A simple wrapper for use with `with` statement
    def __enter__ (self):
        self.session = SQLAlchemySession()
        return self.session
    def __exit__ (self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type:
            self.session.rollback()
        else:
            self.session.commit()
        self.session.close()

with Session() as session:  # Create a record to play with
    if session.query(CrawlerPage) \
              .filter(CrawlerPage.url == 'url').count() == 0:
        session.add(CrawlerPage(website='website', url='url',
                    first_seen=datetime.utcnow()))
    page = session.query(CrawlerPage) \
                  .filter(CrawlerPage.url == 'url') \
                  .one()
    page.failed_count = 0
# commit

# Actual experiment:
with Session() as session:
    page = session.query(CrawlerPage) \
                  .filter(CrawlerPage.url == 'url') \
                  .one()
    print 'initial (session)', page.failed_count
          # 0 (expected)
    page.failed_count += 5
    with Session() as other_session:
        same_page = other_session.query(CrawlerPage) \
                                 .filter(CrawlerPage.url == 'url') \
                                 .one()
        print 'initial (other_session)', same_page.failed_count
              # 0 (expected)
        same_page.failed_count += 10
        print 'final (other_session)', same_page.failed_count
              # 10 (expected)
    # commit other_session, no errors (expected)
    print 'final (session)', page.failed_count
          # 5 (expected)
# commit session, no errors (why?)

with Session() as session:
    page = session.query(CrawlerPage) \
                  .filter(CrawlerPage.url == 'url') \
                  .one()
    print 'final value', page.failed_count
          # 5 (expected, given that there were no errors)
```

**(Apparently Incorrect) Expectations:**

I would have expected that reading a value from a record then updating that value within the same transaction would:

1. Be an atomic operation. That is, either succeed completely or fail completely. This much appears to be true, since the final value is 5, the value set in the last transaction to be committed.
2. Fail if the record being updated is updated by a concurrent session (other_session) upon attempting to commit the transaction. My rationale is that all transactions should behave as though they are performed independently in order of commit whenever possible, or should fail to commit. In these circumstances, the two transactions read then update the same value of the same record. In a version-control system, this would be the equivalent of a merge conflict. Obviously databases are not the same as version-control systems, but they have enough similarities to inform some of my assumptions about them, for better or worse.

**Questions:**

- Why doesn't the second commit raise an exception?

  - Am I misunderstanding something about how SQLAlchemy handles transactions?
  - Am I misunderstanding something about how postgresql handles transactions? (This one seems most likely to me.)
  - Something else?
- Is there a way to get the second commit to raise an exception?

Comment: I've found some information here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html

Comment: And here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) has `select . . . for update`, which [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/changelog/migration_09.html) seems to support.

> My rationale is that all transactions should behave as though they are
>   performed independently in order of commit whenever possible, or
>   should fail to commit.

Well, in general there's a lot more to transactions than that. PostgreSQL's default transaction isolation level is "read committed". Loosely speaking, that means multiple transactions can simultaneously *read* committed values from the same rows in a table. If you want to prevent that, `set transaction isolation serializable` (might not work), or `select...for update`, or lock the table, or use a column-by-column WHERE clause, or whatever.

You can test and demonstrate transaction behavior by opening two psql connections.

```
begin transaction;              begin transaction;
select * 
from test 
where pid = 1 
  and date = '2014-10-01' 
for update;
(1 row)
                                select * 
                                from test 
                                where pid = 1 
                                  and date = '2014-10-01' 
                                for update;
                                (waiting)
update test 
set date = '2014-10-31' 
where pid = 1 
  and date = '2014-10-01';

commit;
                                 -- Locks released. SELECT for update fails.
                                 (0 rows)
```